# Copy a ODBC-linked SQL-Table to an Access table with VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have some ODBC-linked SQL-Server tables in my Access DB, which are the production environment. For testing I want to copy all the data from the SQL-Server into structure-identical Access tables so that I have an identical set of tables in a dev or test-environment. To make it difficult: All of these tables have autoincrement IDs and I want the copies to have the same values and of course the copied ID field also as autoincrement long.

So, a set of these tables:
- dbo_tbl_Abcd
- dbo_tbl_Efgh etc.

should be copied to:
- Dev_Abcd
- Dev_Efgh etc.

or to:
- Test_Abcd
- Test_Efgh etc.

When I do a manual copy and paste for each single table this will work without problems. A dialog "Paste Table As" appears where you have the options:

Linked Table
Structure Only
Structure and Data
Append Data to Existing Table

When you set the name correctly and choose Structure and Data, you will have a proper copy as Access table with the same values in the Auto-ID field. I just want to do this by code and for all ODBC-Tables at once (in a loop). When Access provides this manual copying, there must be a way to do this by code.

I have already tried this:

```
DoCmd.CopyObject , "Dev_Abcd", acTable, "dbo_tbl_Abcd"
```

but this only will create more ODBC-links to the same SQL-Server tables.
I also tried this:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", CurrentDb.Name, acTable, "dbo_tbl_Abcd", "Dev_Abcd"
```

This led to the following error:
*The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object . Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. (Error 3011)*

I experimented a lot with DoCmd.TransferDatabase, but cound't find a working setting.

I did not test any "SELECT INTO"-Statements because of the autoincrement field.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `SELECT ... INTO ...` and auto-increment fields? It generally works great for me.

Comment: Maybe lack of primary key, indexes, defaults, refs in resulting table is a problem?

Comment: Well, if you want to copy those you need more advanced code than a simple copy. You'd need to manually copy those.

Comment: You don't want to export from Access, but to import from SQL Server. So something like `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC", "your ODBC_String", ...` could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking can be done like

CurrentDb.Execute "select *  into localTable from  dbo_serverTable" , dbFailOnError

And to do this to all the tables use this sub

```
   Sub importSrverTables()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs       
            If Left(LCase(tdf.Name), 4) = "dbo_" Then
                'CurrentDb.Execute "select * into localTable from  dbo_serverTable", dbFailOnError
                db.Execute "select * into " & Mid(tdf.Name, 5) & " from  " & tdf.Name, dbFailOnError
       ' the next if is to make the loop wait until the transfer finish.
        If db.RecordsAffected > 0 Then
        ' do nothing
        End If
            End If         
    Next
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
   End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Guys, thank you for your help. now I've chosen this solution with an additional `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ID ON <Tablename> (<FirstField>) WITH PRIMARY`.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similiar. Change the ConnectionString to your environment. Maybe you have to extend the TranslateDatatype function.

```
Function TranslateDatatype(value As Long) As String
  Select Case value
    Case 2: TranslateDatatype = "INT" ' adSmallInt
    Case 3: TranslateDatatype = "LONG" ' adInteger
    Case 200: TranslateDatatype = "STRING" ' adVarChar
    Case 202: TranslateDatatype = "STRING" ' adVarWChar
    Case 17: TranslateDatatype = "BYTE" ' adUnsignedTinyInt
    Case 11: TranslateDatatype = "BIT" ' adBoolean
    Case 129: TranslateDatatype = "STRING" ' adChar
    Case 135: TranslateDatatype = "DATE" ' adDBTimeStamp
    Case Else: Err.Raise "You have to extend TranslateDatatype with value " & value
  End Select
End Function

Sub CopyFromSQLServer()
  Dim SQLDB As Object, rs As Object, sql As String, i As Integer, tdf As TableDef
  Dim ConnectionString As String
  Set SQLDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=YourSQLServer;Database=YourDatabase;trustedConnection=yes"
  SQLDB.Open ConnectionString
  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Set rs.ActiveConnection = SQLDB
  For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    rs.Source = "[" & tdf.Name & "]"
    rs.Open
    sql = "("
    i = 0
    Do
      sql = sql & "[" & rs(i).Name & "] " & TranslateDatatype(rs(i).Type) & ", "
      i = i + 1
    Loop Until i = rs.Fields.Count
    rs.Close
    sql = "CREATE TABLE [Dev_" & tdf.Name & "] " & Left(sql, Len(sql) - 2) & ")"
    CurrentDb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
    sql = "INSERT INTO [Dev_" & tdf.Name & "] SELECT * FROM [" & tdf.Name & "]"
    CurrentDb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
  Next
End Sub
```